# Why `int(0) and boolean` returns `int(0)` instead `boolean(false)`?

Tags: javascript, comparison

Specifically (I don't know if it can happen in others case), when I do `int(0) && boolean` with `myString.length && myString === "true"` when `myString = ""`, it returns `0` instead of returns a boolean.

```
alert((function() {
    var myString = "";
    return myString.length && myString === "true";
})());
```

I know that I can fix it by do `myString.length !== 0` or casting with `Boolean`. But I like to understand why `&&` don't force cast the left side to boolean.

**Live example**: http://jsfiddle.net/uqma4ahm/1/

Comment: Because that's what the spec says.  (this is quite useful)

Answer (score 4):

The `&&` operator in JavaScript returns the actual value of whichever one of its subexpression operands is last evaluated. In your case, when `.length` is `0`, that expression is the last to be evaluated because `0` is "falsy".

The operator *does* perform a coercion to boolean of the subexpression value(s), but it only uses that result to determine how to proceed. The overall value of the `&&` is thus not necessarily boolean; it will be boolean only when the last subexpression evaluated had a boolean result.

This JavaScript behavior is distinctly different from the behavior of the similar operator in C, C++, Java, etc.

Comment: +1, I never knew about this in JavaScript (that's because we don't usually read the spec) Thanks for info :)

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` operator yields *the left hand value if it is [false-y](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)<sup>1</sup>* and the right-hand value otherwise. (Unlike some languages, it is *not* guaranteed to evaluate to true or false!)

TTL for A && B:

```
A         B     (A && B)
false-y   -     A
truth-y   -     B
```

To make sure that *only* true or false is returned, it is easy to apply (double) negation:

```
return !!(myString.length && myString === "true")
```

or, equivalently

```
return !(!myString.length || myString !== "true")
```

Here is the negation TTL which leads to deriving `!!(false-y) => false` and `!!(truth-y) => true`.

```
A         !A      !(!A)
false-y   true    false
truth-y   false   true
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In JavaScript the false-y values are false 0, "", null, undefined, NaN. While everything else is truth-y.